# Get the value of select item from Ruby simple_form menu and count results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using simple_form and i have a select menu with 3 values, which get printed to the index. I want to know the correct and best way to get the value that the users sets, and then do a count of how many of the 3 different choices there currently are.

I'm new to ruby so this is a big learning curve and any help will be appreciated.

**In my _form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.input :menu, :as => :select, :collection => [ "Chocolate", "Cake", "Custard"] %>
```

**My Index.html.erb**

```
<td><%= reply.menu %></td>
```

**db**

```
class CreateReplies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :replies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :menu
      t.boolean :rsvp, :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're looking to do a many-to-one relationship (many replies to one menu)
2. Change your migration to be t.integer :menu_id
3. Create another model called Menu with and id and i.e. name.

So roll with something like the following:

```
#  == Schema Information
#
#  Table name: replies
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  menu_id     :integer
#  ...
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null


class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :menu_id, etc.
  belongs_to :menu, :inverse_of => :replies # belongs_to because has the FK 
 ...
end

#  == Schema Information
#  
#  Table name: menus
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null


class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :replies, :inverse_of => :menu, :dependent => :nullify # the FK is in the reply
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies
end
```

And then since you're using SimpleForm:

```
 <%= f.association :menu, :collection => Menu.all, :prompt => "- Select -"%>
```

Then everything else is for the most part automated for you (i.e. when you create/update a reply it'll grab the posted menu_id and assign it accordingly.

If I were you, I'd dig into http://ruby.railstutorial.org/. It's an excellent resource.

Update: forgot about your view display (if you're trying to display the name of the menu you selected - if you're trying to display an entire menu, that's a whole other different scenario):

```
<td><%= @reply.menu.name %></td>
```

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, still working this one out. Where you have the table Schema info, im assuming i do a db migrate to adjust my db. I know thats probably a noobie question, but just so im clear

Comment: The schema info just shows what fields would be in your database  for that model (the comment notation in the actual model is generated using a handy gem called "annotate"). Yes, you'll need to create a migration that will create those fields and db:migrate and db:test:prepare.

Comment: May i ask why the bottom table :menus is commented out? Sorry, new to this

Comment: For convenience I just plunked in the annotated info (sort of inaccurately in terms of what is commented and what is not primarily while trying to quickly get SO to format it properly) that details the underlying table schema. As it appears it might be confusing you more than helping, just remove the schema notes. In the meantime I'll look at it again and make sure the schema info is all set as comments, which is how it should be (other than, of course, in your migrations!).

Comment: After much reading and playing around - I finally managed it, and it works perfectly. Thank you and sorry it took so long for me to get it!